# How can i revert collaborator's changes in his commits and keep my changes in my commits in the same branch?

Tags: git

Tom and I are working on a feature branch.

- Tom made some changes first, committed and pushed to github.
- Then I pulled from github, made some changes elsewhere, committed and pushed to github.

Now I would like to

- revert all the changes he has made, and
- keep my changes.

What commands can I use?

- How can I identify all the commits that he pushed to github?
- how can I revert the changes made in the identified commits of his, while keeping my changes in my commits?

Thanks.

Comment: Did any of your commits build on top of any of Tom's commits?

Comment: My changes were in different places from his changes.

Comment: Do you want to rewrite history (as if Tom never had done anything) or do you just want to add commits that undo the changes Tom made?

Comment: We are working on a branch. I would like to revert what he did on the branch, without modifying the history

Comment: You can use `git log --author tom` to see commits made by "tom" (add `--stat` or `-p` to get more information). Use `git revert COMMIT` to revert a particular commit (or `git revert COMMIT1..COMMIT2` for a range of commits).

Comment: @melpomene 1. How can I find out his username used in git? 2. I made commits after he did. Will `git revert COMMIT` to revert his commits also affect my commits? 3. I manually reverted some of his changes. Will `git revert COMMIT` on his commits meet some problem?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 2):

This is an amalgam of two commands - `git log` and `git revert`.

We'll use `git log` to determine which commits he did.  It's up to you to determine which commit to "stop" at, though.

First, `git log` to pull a listing of all of the commits that they've done on a specific branch:

```
git log --graph --author="Tom" --oneline --decorate --pretty <branch>
```

From that, you can get a list of all of Tom's commits.

Now, you can use `git revert` to specify a range of commits to revert.  Suppose that the last commit he did was `ffffff`, and the first he did was `aaaaaa`, you'd write this:

```
git revert aaaaaa^..ffffff
```

This will create a revert commit which undoes all of Tom's work between those ranges.  If any of Tom's work touched yours, you'll know about it here and you'll need to figure out the best approach to diagnose/resolve the issue.  To get it back, you have to revert the revert.

Comment: Thanks. see my comments above.